# How to ignore reponse data from when send Post request?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I send Post request by follow code:

```
try
            {
                string responseContent;
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                // Set Method to "POST"
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Set the content type of the WebRequest
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3";
                // Set the content length
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(requestCommand);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    // Write the "POST" data to the stream
                    requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (BufferedStream buffer = new BufferedStream(responseStream))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buffer))
                            {
                                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return responseContent;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
}
```

It's works ok. But the code lines below is so slow.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buffer))
{
   responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I don't know why! I have spend more time to find out solution, such at set proxy = null,... but no results.
Are there any way to ignore that line. I dont need to receive response data. I have tried replace that lines by:

```
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   responseStream.Flush();
   responseStream.Close();
}
```

But I can't send Post request correctly and sucessfuly. Please help me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care at all about the response or whether it fails, you can probably queue up the response on a new thread and just ignore it.

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Write the "POST" data to the stream
    requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}

// now put the get response code in a new thread and immediately return
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
{
    using (var objResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        objResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(responseStream);
        responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     }
});
```